# How to stop a killed rollback process on MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, kill-process

We have a failed attempt of a rollback on a Mariabd. The process is still listed in `show full processlist` but show no progress. How to stop this process?

```
22301639    user    localhost   db  Killed  20334   Rollback    insert into `table`(...     0.000
```

`KILL 22301639;` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The rollback is (probably) a consequence of a killed statement - not the subject. Unless you intend restoring from backup best to let it run to completion.

Comment: could very well be. but the rollback was also programmed as a PDOException handler.  We just realized the table was as large as 50GB with over 50mi records which should never be that large. It looks like a programming bug generating this amount of records. The transaction was part of a testing procedure so we can live without the table and recreate it. But that seems not to be possible in this stage (and yes it ran fine on the dev enironment)